# Allow authenticated user to see only their data

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6, php-7.2

Right now I have authentication setup but when an authenticated user creates new data, any authenticated user can see that data and manipulate it. I would like to make it so that each user can only see the data they created. I am new to laravel and php so I don't really know how to set this up!

I can share any code or more details if needed, just let me know!

Thanks

Comment: Go for it. Let us know how it works out.

Comment: To ask an On Topic question, please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
 and [What topics to avoid](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)
 and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 and [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)
 **We are very willing to help you fix your code, but we dont write code for you**

Comment: use Gate https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authorization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the ways to do it is to create a `user_id` foreign key in your data table. Then filter data against logged in user id.

For example you have a products table. Create a `user_id` foreign key in products table. Then setup relationship between products and users. So when you show all products info, filter products that matches logged in user id.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: thank you that helps! I'll go try and implement this!

Comment: If you think this will help you, please accept it as answer!!! :-)

Comment: Thank you....!!!

Comment: NO!!! Thank You!

Comment: You helped me out!

Comment: Let me know if you need more on this topic

Comment: I definitely will and I will follow you

Comment: Thank you.......